# Google Account DropDown in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

Are there any jQuery or Javascript solutions for creating a menu similar to the one Google uses for their user accounts? Below is an image of what I'm talking about. If you login to Google you can see a demonstration of the drop down in the top right.

[image]

Comment: The solution is simple, really. Create a floating div that is styled the way that Google's is, and use jQuery's `click` handler to toggle its show/hide. If you want that click to be on the image of a gear, that's up to you.

Check out the jQuery UI project for more of this type of baked-in functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something a little more fancy than a simple div, I'm sure you'll be able to find something along those lines here:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Number six on the list, the 'CSS3 Mega Drop Down Menu' looks like it could easily be modified to act like Google's account dropdown menu.